# The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ satisfy $f(0) = 3,$ $g(0) = -4,$ and $f'(x) = 7f(x) + 2g(x)$ and $g'(x) = -4f(x) + g(x).$ Find $f(x).$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ satisfy $f(0) = 3,$ $g(0) = -4,$ and
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= 7f(x) + 2g(x), \\
g'(x) &= -4f(x) + g(x).
\end{align*}Find $f(x).$
I'm not sure how to solve the following system of equations, could someone please help? I got the general form of $f(x)$ to be $(c_1+2c_2)e^{5x}-(c_1+c_2)e^{3x}$ for constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, but I'm not sure how to find these constants using the initial conditions. Thanks!

Comment: Represent $g'$ completely in terms of $f$. Then differentiate $(1)$ one time. You get a second ODE.

Comment: Do you know already what eigenvalues and eigenvectors are?

Comment: In other words, you need to provide some context for this problem (and what you do know about it—you have to have some thoughts!), so that we know what kind of direction to go in.

Comment: I got the general form of $f(x)$ to be $(c_1+2c_2)e^{5t} -(c_1+c_2) e^{3t}$ for constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, but I'm not sure how to find these constants using the initial conditions.

Comment: hum, try using the initial conditions, such as $f(0)$, the equation for $f'(x)$ (with $x=0$) and $g(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is set up a system of equations by applying the initial conditions, as jDAQ mentioned. Before setting up the equations, I will just mention that you should also include $g(x):$
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=(c_1+2c_2)e^{5x}-(c_1+c_2)e^{3x}\\
g(x)&=-(c_1+2c_2)e^{5x}+2(c_1+c_2)e^{3x}.
\end{align*}

Here's how it would look:
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=3\\
g(0)&=-4\\
(c_1+2c_2)-(c_1+c_2)&=3\\
-(c_1+2c_2)+2(c_1+c_2)&=-4\\
c_2&=3\\
c_1&=-4.
\end{align*}
Then just re-write $f$ and $g$ with these values plugged in.

Comment: Thaks so much for your help, this really cleared everything up :))